# I need to change my submit button class

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I need to change form left to right layout and right to left when i press the button here is my code :

```
<form method="post">
<ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="right" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>
</form>
```

now I need to add an if statement like :

```
if(isset($_POST['left'])) {
echo '    <ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="right" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>';
}
if(isset($_POST['right'])){
{
echo '    <ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="right" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="left" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>';
}
```

Comment: no because when I press any button another row of buttons come on my page

Comment: You can also use jQuery for this.

Comment: I need php because i don't know any jQuery at this time

Comment: It sounds like you need to save the chosen option to a `$_SESSION` variable so it doesn't change when another button is clicked. But frankly, it's difficult to understand both what you are attempting to accomplish and what problem you are encountering. Please give a little more information about what isn't working.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `if/elseif/else` construction you can implement it like this:

```
echo '<form method="post">';
if(isset($_POST['left'])) {
echo '    <ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="right" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>';
} elseif(isset($_POST['right'])){
echo '    <ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="right" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="left" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>';
} else {
 echo '
<ul>
 <li class="left">
    <input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left">
 </li>
 <li class="right">
  <input name="right" type="submit" class="right" value="right">
 </li>
 </ul>';
}

echo  '</form>';
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is working code:

```
<form method="post" action="#">
<?php

if(isset($_POST['left'])) {
    echo '<ul><li class="left"><input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left"></li><li class="right"><input name="right" type="submit" class="right" value="right"></li></ul>';
}
if(isset($_POST['right'])){
    echo '<ul><li class="right"><input name="right" type="submit" class="left" value="right"></li><li class="left"><input name="left" type="submit" class="right" value="left"></li></ul>';
}

if(!isset($_POST['right']) && !isset($_POST['left'])){
    echo '<ul><li class="left"><input name="left" type="submit" class="right" value="left"></li><li class="right"><input name="right" type="submit" class="left" value="right"></li></ul>';
}
?>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use php for this you could use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/)

JQuery has a toogle class:

http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/

Use this to toogle the input from right to left

Example:

HTML:

```
  <form method="post">
    <ul>
     <button class="changeside">Change side</button>
     <li class="left">
        <input name="left" type="submit" class="left" value="left">
     </li>
     </ul>
    </form>
```

Javascript

```
 <script>
    $( ".changeside" ).click(function() {
      $( this ).toggleClass( "left" );
      $( this ).toggleClass( "right" );
    });
    </script>
```